# Adding View to Padding area of GridLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridlayout

Is it possible (or acceptable) to add an image on top of the top padding area of a GridLayout?

I have a GridLayout which resembles a calculator - lots of buttons, and I have a background that makes the calculator look like its made out of metal. What I want to do it put a screen image on top of the calculator.

So far I have used the setPadding() method so that all of the buttons appear further down the screen, leaving enough space for the screen. I guess what I should be doing is making a new row for the screen within the GridLayout but I was wondering: Is is possible to add an ImageView on top of the GridLayout in that padding area, or is this a big "no no" and should I be creating a new row instead?

```
.. buttons already added to gridLayout
gridLayout.setBackground( drawableMetalBackground );

ImageView iv = new ImageView( this );  // 'this' context should be gridLayout context??

iv.setBackground( npdScreen );

iv.layout( 0, 0, 300, 100 );  // Hardcode positions for example
gridLayout.addView( iv );
```

Comment: 1. Wrap them both in a parent layout. 2. Use xml. 3. Stop the hardcoding!

Comment: @ElDuderino: I would gladly use XML all the time if it would allow rows and columns of GridLayout to nicely occupy the full display and only hardcode when trying to get test apps to work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution I would say is to use a seperate row for the ImageView. Thats what I did and its working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a XML layout for you to use. The `GridLayout` elements are just for example, but you can use it for your purpose changing it for the buttons of your calculator.

As you can see, the orientation of the `LinearLayout` is set to vertical, and the `layout_width` and `layout_height` are set to `match_parent`, which means that both will occupy the entire screen. Also there is a padding in all sides to keep a distance from the edge of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/Lighthouse"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<GridLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:text="/" />
    <Button android:text="1" />
    <Button android:text="2" />
    <Button android:text="3" />
    <Button android:text="*" />
    <Button android:text="4" />
    <Button android:text="5" />
    <Button android:text="6" />
    <Button android:text="-" />
    <Button android:text="7" />
    <Button android:text="8" />
    <Button android:text="9" />
    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:text="+" />
    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="0" />
    <Button android:text="00" />
    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="=" />

</GridLayout>
```

And here is the final result for this XML layout. The image background on the `ImageView` is just a simple image I've placed on drawable folder.
[image]

**Hope it helps you.**